# .net Core auto ejecutable

Tags: linux, .net, .net-core

Después de crear mi primera aplicación de consola con **.Net Core 1.1** en Windows 10 con Visual Studio 2017 copié a mi servidor **Linux - Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS** (ya con el framework .Net Core instalado).

He ejecutado con éxito el comando:
Windows

`> Dotnet miApp.dll`

Linux

`$ Dotnet miApp.dll`

Ahora quiero tener un **ejecutable independiente**, sin necesidad de **dotnet** para ejecutar. ¿Como hago?
Deseo realizar así:
Windows

`> MiApp.exe`

Linux

`$ ./minhaApp`

Comment: ¿Qué versión del SDK de .net core estás usando?

Comment: Es .net core 1.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es compilar la aplicación de consola según el modelo [*Self-contained deployment o Implementación Autocontenida*](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/core/deploying/).

La ventaja es que ya no requerirá de .Net Core instalado en la máquina de destino y por lo tanto se podrá ejecutar sin necesidad de hacerlo a través del comando dotnet. La desventaja es que el ejecutable ya no será portable y deberá compilarse para cada plataforma específica para la cual necesitas el ejecutable.

Para hacerlo de esta forma edita tu archivo `.csproj` y agrégale el tag `<RuntimeIdentifiers>` dentro de `<PropertyGroup>` y coloca una lista separadas por `;` de los Ids de las plataformas a las que quieres compilar. La lista completa de ids la puedes consultar aquí: [.NET Core Runtime IDentifier (RID) catalog](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog)

Ejemplo de `.csproj` de una app de consola

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x64;ubuntu.16.04-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Luego de esto compila en modo Release y crea tantos perfiles de publicación como plataformas hacia donde vayas a compilar.

Asegurate de colocar los perfiles en carpetas diferentes y con plataformas diferentes.

Ejemplo de perfil de publicación en Windows

[image: Ejemplo de perfil de publicación en Windows]

Ejemplo de perfil de publicación en Ubuntu

[image: Ejemplo de perfil de publicación en Ubuntu]

Finalemente los archivos ya listos para ser desplegados estarán en las rutas que le colocaste en los perfiles de publicación. Ten en cuenta que se generan muchísimos archivos (En mi caso 118 en Windows y 123 en Ubuntu) ya que incluyen no solo tu app sino todo el .Net Core necesario para que la app sea totalmente autosuficiente.

Answer (score 0):

Cómo te indico Carlos debes generar una aplicación autocontenida.

Por comandos puedes hacerlo así

```
dotnet build –c Release –r win10-x64
```

La lista de valores posibles es amplia y desde luego es actualizada cada tanto. algunos de los otros valores posibles son estos dependiendo del OS al que quieras generar el ejecutable.

```
win7-x64
win10-x64
osx.10.11-x64
ubuntu.16.04-x64
```